# i made a program to calculate sales tax, when ever i put in 1.0 as the tax rate it doesn't double?

Tags: java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication19;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author joshu
 */
public class JavaApplication19 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // also please don't block me this is my second time using this site

    System.out.println("// SALES_TAX////////////////////////////////////");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String emailAddress;
    double itemPrice, itemAmount, SALES_TAX;

    System.out.println("How many item will you like to buy?");
    itemAmount = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("What is the price of the item?");
    itemPrice = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter sales tax rate: ");
    SALES_TAX = input.nextDouble();

    final Double SalesTaxRate = SALES_TAX * itemPrice;
    double totalprice = SalesTaxRate + (itemPrice * itemAmount);

    emailAddress = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter emailAddress");
    emailAddress = input.nextLine();

    System.out.printf("Your total price is: $ %1.2f" + " a copy of this invoice"
    + " will be emailed to: %s\n",
    totalprice,emailAddress.toUpperCase());

    System.out.println("///////////////////////////////////////////");   





    }

}
```

Comment: So have you debugged into the code? At which point does it behave in a way other than what you expect?

Comment: im a beginner so im still learning so I don't know if it's a problem with my code or the way I write my percentage because im trying to double the price by having a hundred percent tax rate

Comment: One thing I see - you're adding SalesTaxRate to price*amount; so tax will only be charged once.

Comment: Well, now's a good time to learn to use the debugger. You should be able work out what you *expect* the state of the program to be at any line, and you should be able to *check* the state of the program with the debugger. Once you've narrowed it down to a specific part of the code that's not working, you can ask a more specific question if you need to.

Comment: `SalesTaxRate + (itemPrice * itemAmount)` is wrong - if you're purchasing $20 of items and the the tax rate is 10%, for example, then the correct total price is $22, **not** $20.10 (which is what you're doing now).

Comment: Your code works exactly how you coded it. What's the output you're expecting?

Comment: yeah, so I put the price 10 and the amount 5 in which changed the values like it should have.  Then I inputted t the sales tax rate (1.0) which is 100% and the value change 1.0 and then it did the math and gave me 55 instead of 100

Comment: @JoshuaCarpentier You are not taking into account the itemAmount when calculating the SalesTaxRate (Which isn't the rate but the actual sales tax to be paid, not good naming). Also what you just posted is just plain wrong. When you enter the values you just said you get 60$ as an answer as i would expect it (With just one Item having it's price doubled instead all of them). You probably entered amount 10 and price 5.

Comment: Please see the complete implementation here: https://github.com/gmershad/Sales-Tax

Answer (score 1):

This line is problematic for starters:

```
final Double SalesTaxRate = SALES_TAX * itemPrice;
double totalprice = SalesTaxRate + (itemPrice * itemAmount);
```

You're only adding the tax rate on a single item, *not* on the total amount.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the logic for your total calculations like so:

```
//gets the percentage of the item, and then adds the item price
    final Double SalesTaxRate = itemPrice + (itemPrice * (SALES_TAX / 100));

//simply multiply the new price by the amount required
        double totalprice = SalesTaxRate * itemAmount;
```

Comment: If you do it like that, you probably want to change the name of `SalesTaxRate`.

Comment: The naming is a bit of an issue all round!